# How to align various parts of the title?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, titles

I am attempting to recreate the following title look, from scratch

[image]

Here is my attempt so far:

```
\documentclass[paper=A4, fontsize =11pt ]{scrartcl} % A4 Paper and 11pt font size 
\usepackage[english]{babel} % English language 
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amsthm,amssymb} % American Mathematical Society packages
\usepackage{geometry} % Geometry package 
\usepackage{datetime } % Date and time  package 

\usepackage{fancyhdr} % Custom headers and footers
\pagestyle{fancyplain} % Makes all pages in the document conform to the custom headers and footers
\fancyhead{} % Removes page header 
\fancyfoot{} % Removes page footer 
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % Remove header underlines
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt} % Remove footer underlines


\title{
\normalfont \normalsize 
\text{Long title element} \\ [11pt]  
\text{Title element}\\ [14pt] 
\begin{flushleft}
Text 
\end{flushleft}
}


\begin{document}
\maketitle
Something
\end{document}
```

The issue that I am struggling with is how to right align the date, but I will appreciate and welcome any other suggestions on how to improve the tex.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You are aware that there's a clear warning that `scr...` classes shouldn't be used with `fancyhdr`?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Yes, I am. Alternatives?

Comment: The `scr....` classes and `scrlayer-scrpage` package provide the relevant settings, with 'similar' command names

Comment: You should be aware that the datetime package is obsolete and was replaced by datetime2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply modify your `flushleft` environment to

```
\begin{flushleft}
Text \hfill \today
\end{flushleft}
```

I am just overlooking for the moment, how to prevent the `\maketitle` to print an additional date.

```
\documentclass[paper=A4, fontsize =11pt ]{scrartcl} % A4 Paper and 11pt font size 
\usepackage[english]{babel} % English language 
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amsthm,amssymb} % American Mathematical Society packages
\usepackage{geometry} % Geometry package 
\usepackage{datetime2} % Date and time  package 

\usepackage{fancyhdr} % Custom headers and footers
\pagestyle{fancyplain} % Makes all pages in the document conform to the custom headers and footers
\fancyhead{} % Removes page header 
\fancyfoot{} % Removes page footer 
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % Remove header underlines
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt} % Remove footer underlines


\title{
\normalfont \normalsize 
\text{Long title element} \\ [11pt]  
\text{Title element}\\ [14pt] 
\begin{flushleft}
Text \hfill \today
\end{flushleft}
}


\begin{document}
\maketitle
Something
\end{document}
```